# Is excessive use of setState code-smell / anti-pattern?

Tags: flutter

I am newbie to Flutter but I inherited a 10K SLOC project that I need to refactor. The developers used setState in the widgets classes vey often. like 10 times for single widget class. Isn't the whole point of Flutter is to be reactive without the need to notify the UI to rebuild ?
If yes, how to fix this ? Thanks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efpjQ.png)

Comment: Hi and wellcome to StackOverflow; next time post your code instead of a screenshot. You can format the code in the question with backticks.

Answer (score 1):

> I am newbie to Flutter but I inherited a 10K SLOC project that I need to refactor.

This is a first smell for me: if you've just started Dart and Flutter, there's a good chance that refactoring and improve other's code is not a good idea.

> The developers used setState in the widgets classes very often

It might have sense, it might have no sense. But yes, usually `setState` is used to handle ephimeral state, where as other techniques such as [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev/) handle global / subglobal state. So yes, there's a good chance that over-using `setState` is a code smell.

> Isn't the whole point of Flutter is to be reactive without the need to notify the UI to rebuild?

Not really. [As the documentation tells](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/declarative), Flutter is a declarative framework, but this doesn't mean that Flutter magically handle rebuilds for you. The purpose of `setState` is indeed to update... state. And then Flutter takes the wheel from there, re-rendering the whole subtree. But it is your responsibility as a developer to update state. Yes, `setState` is actually a pretty *explicit* way to do so, and it feels like telling the framework "ok, repaint now", but this can be desired. Again, you should check other state management approaches to avoid using `setState` everywhere and update the widgets without explicitly telling the framework to do so.

Good luck with your gig.